# how to mark minimum stability when Loading a package from a git repository on composer

Tags: php, laravel, git, composer-php

I was using this library in my composer

```
"require": {
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "@RC",
```

and it basically pulled this tag from said repo: `1.0.0-rc.4.1`

I forked the above repo and added a commit on top of the above tag, and put it in a branch called [curly-brace-parser](https://github.com/totersapp/jwt-auth/tree/curly-brace-parser).

I updated my composer.json like so:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/totersapp/jwt-auth"
    },
"require" {
    "tymon/jwt-auth": "dev-curly-brace-parser@RC",
```

but when I run `` I get this error:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

> Problem 1
>       - The requested package tymon/jwt-auth dev-curly-brace-parser@RC exists as tymon/jwt-auth[0.1.0, 0.2.0, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.10, 0.3.11,
>   0.3.12, 0.3.2, 0.3.3, 0.3.4, 0.3.5, 0.3.6, 0.3.7, 0.3.8, 0.3.9, 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.5.0, 0.5.1, 0.5.10, 0.5.11, 0.5.12, 0.5.2, 0.5.3, 0.5.4, 0.5.5, 0.5.6, 0.5.7, 0.5.8, 0.5.9, 1.0.0-alpha.2, 1.0.0-alpha.3, 1.0.0-alpha1, 1.0.0-beta.1, 1.0.0-beta.2, 1.0.0-beta.3, 1.0.0-rc.1, 1.0.0-rc.2, 1.0.0-rc.3, 1.0.0-rc.4, 1.0.0-rc.4.1, 2.0.x-dev, dev-dependabot/composer/phpunit/phpunit-tw-8.3.3, dev-dependabot/composer/phpunit/phpunit-tw-8.3.4, dev-develop,
>   1.0.x-dev, dev-master] but these are rejected by your constraint.
>
> Problem 2
>       - The requested package waavi/translation (locked at 2.3.4, required as dev-extractGenCodeLatest) is satisfiable by
>   waavi/translation[2.3.4] but these conflict with your requirements or
>   minimum-stability.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After going through this [composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#stability) I learned that I need to create a tag instead of rely on the branch name (as one solution).. so I did this on my jwt library:

[image]

I updated the tag from `1.0.0-rc.4.1` to `1.0.0-rc.4.2` and then made the requirement

```
"tymon/jwt-auth": "@RC",
```

as before and it worked!